# ASP.NET long Name attribute - Why is there no ClientNameMode

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET much has been made about the ClientIdMode property that gives developers greater control over the a control's ID attribute as it appears in the HTML.

However little attention appears to have be paid to the way the controls render their Name attribute.  It appears to be a simple concatenation of the control's ID and its hierarchy of naming containers.

Given a sufficiently complex web page these names get very long. They not only make the HTML payload big (and ugly) but are also posted back to the server on every postback.  (Also, they make their way into the Control State of some third party control suites. )

Why isn't there a ClientNameMode property - or similar? Surely it is as important as the Id attribute?  Is it possible to override some method that generates / rehydrates the Name attribute so that we can man handle it to maybe match the Id? (made shorter by the ClientIdMode)

An example of a name of a control on a page that I am working on is

```
USoWAR1_tabContainer_UDetailsTabContainer_tabContainer_UDetailsTab_UDetails1_UDueDateAndNotifications1_decDetail_DataEntryRow1_datDueDate_DateTimePicker_calendar_AD
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to alter this functionality is to extend controls into your own and override `UniqueID` property (e.g. by returning Server-side ID).

Comment: Sure. You can do that but the entire postback mechanism of ASP.net preserving the state of the controls and identifying changes in control values stops working.

Comment: UniqueID on the server == Name on the client, I don't think it's as important as ClientID in page lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and had to use `JS` to set the `attr` after loading.

```
$('#idofdomobjiwanttoname').attr("name", "whatIWantToNameIt");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't include just a link as an answer, either expand on it so the link is not needed, or post it as a comment instead.